# Laravel - VUE not recognized in blade

Tags: laravel, vue.js, algolia

I am trying to set up laravel scout with Algolia.

I am following Algolia indications from:
https://www.algolia.com/doc/framework-integration/laravel/searching/client-side-search/?language=php

The problem I am facing is when I try to use VUE in the blade with the following code:

```
......
<script src="{{ asset('public/js/app.js') }}"></script> <!-- I have tried async too -->
......

    <div id="app">
      <!-- In a default Laravel app, Vue will render inside an #app div -->
      <ais-instant-search
        :search-client="searchClient"
        index-name="{{ (new App\Article)->searchableAs() }}"
      >
        <ais-search-box placeholder="Search articles..."></ais-search-box>

        <ais-hits>
          <template slot="item" slot-scope="{ item }">
            <div>
              <h1>@{{ item.title }}</h1>
              <h4>@{{ item.summary }}</h4>
            </div>
          </template>
        </ais-hits>
      </ais-instant-search>
    </div>

    <script>
    new Vue({
      data: function() {
        return {
          searchClient: algoliasearch(
            '{{ config('scout.algolia.id') }}',
            '{{ Algolia\ScoutExtended\Facades\Algolia::searchKey(App\Article::class) }}',
          ),
        };
      },
      el: '#app',
    });
    </script>
```

And my app.js looks like this:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite';
window.algoliasearch = algoliasearch;

import InstantSearch from 'vue-instantsearch';
Vue.use(InstantSearch);
```

I have been reading online load of stuff about the same issue but it does not matter what I try the Vue is not recognized:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
```

Vue can start in app.js because I tried but I need it on the blade because as you can see I need to print some algolia info. Ideas?

Comment: Is your app.js in your assets compiled using webpack and present in public/js directory?

Comment: yes, I compile it with npm run watch and it is load properly

Comment: Where is `app.js` being loaded on the page?  It must be loaded prior to the Vue component.  Do not use `async`.

Comment: I found it out, I am an idiot... the cache was loading the same file and did not recognize the changes on the app.js... feel so dumb

Comment: Just a comment, for what it's worth.  It's much cleaner to put a global `new Vue()` in `app.js` for `el: #app`.  Then you can build components for everything and not mess with Vue logic in blade files.  You just drop in your tags and props where you need things.  It keeps the code much more organized.  — `const app = new Vue({ el: #app });`

Comment: please install proper vue and run following commands
npm install (for install all necessary things)
npm run watch 
npm run hot (if you mix in your code like laravel + vue)
npm run serve